# react native audio - playback failed due to audio decoding error?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs, react-router

I tried to play the audio file from url in react-native-audio. Audio manager tried to play audio file before it got time to load the audio file ...

I looked for this problem in git hub but none of the solution worked... Hope it helps you since it worked for me in android...

```
playback failed due to audio decoding error
static play(audioPath) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Platform.OS === "ios") { 
        Sound.enable(true);
      }
      const sound = new Sound(audioPath, "", (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log("failed to load the sound", error);
        }
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        sound.play((success) => {
          if (success) {
            console.log("successfully finished playing");
          } else {
            // HERE WhAT I Did was just recurr this same function until and unless the audio is download properly and played successfully
            console.log("Error Occurred Retrying");

          }
        });
      }, 100);
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late response but I got stuck with same problem so I am sharing the solution worked for me.
you should play it inside where you load it. I guess its a library mistake.

```js
let sound = new Sound('ding.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
      if (error) {
          console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
      } else {
          sound.play(); // have to put the call to play() in the onload callback
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

playback failed due to audio decoding error

```
static play(audioPath) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Platform.OS === "ios") { 
        Sound.enable(true);
      }
      const sound = new Sound(audioPath, "", (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log("failed to load the sound", error);
        }
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        sound.play((success) => {
          if (success) {
            console.log("successfully finished playing");
          } else {
            // HERE WhAT I Did was just recurr this same function until and unless the audio is download properly and played successfully
            console.log("Error Occurred Retrying");

            this.play(audioPath);
          }
        });
      }, 100);
    }, 100);
```